# How to call an identically-named parent function?

Tags: javascript, function, class, super, function-call

Consider the following code:

```
class Base {
   constructor() {
      let _myPrivateData = 'Base';
      this.print = () => { console.log(_myPrivateData); };
   }
};

class Derived extends Base {
   constructor() { 
      super();
      this.print = () => { this.print(); console.log('Derived'); };
      //                   ↑↑↑↑
   } 
};
```

I've avoided the [methods](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-method-definitions) notations to enforce the privacy of the encapsulated data (i.e. the `_myPrivateData`).
Using `this` (at the marked section) would cause an *"infinite recursion"*. The `super` keyword cannot be used there as it's only valid inside methods. I've also tried the `Base.prototype.print()` to no avails!

So, how to invoke the `print()` function defined in the `Base` class, from inside of an identically-named-function in the `Derived` class?

Comment: Save the value of `this.print` before you override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may save the current value of the `this.print` before overriding it (where it still points to the `print` defined in the `Base` class):

```js
class Base {
   constructor() {
      let _myPrivateData = 'Base';
      this.print = () => { console.log(_myPrivateData); };
   }
};

class Derived extends Base {
   constructor() { 
      super();
      let print = this.print; // <-- Save the current value before overriding
      this.print = () => { print(); console.log('Derived'); };
      //                   ↑↑↑↑↑
   } 
};

var x = new Derived();

x.print();
```